# How to make sure a video has been viewed

Tags: php, object, video

I am designing a website that will provide continuing education courses via streaming video. One of the requirements is that attendance must be tracked. That is, I cannot allow users to navigate to the next video segment until they have actually watched the first video segment. I have written a PHP program that timestamps the loading of the page, saves this to a database table, and then prevents the user from viewing the next video segment until the timestamp has expired. But this is awkward, and it doesn't ensure that the video has actually been played in its entirety. It would be nice if I could somehow interface with the video object to know when it is actually finished playing. Does anyone have any suggestions on the best way to accomplish this?

The videos in question are in .wmv format.

Comment: How do you make sure they were in the room while the video played?

Comment: The attendance tracking thing is a stupid governmental rule. I thought the same thing - so I know the video was playing for a certain amount of time, but how do I know they actually watched it? But, fortunately, that part isn't my problem. My requirements are actually pretty clear this time, for a change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the html5 video tag, you could hook into the events available.

You have events "ended", "playing" etc available to you using javascript.

You can call whatever external function (probably via ajax) if an event is triggered.

Comment: I thought that too, but I don't think HTML5 video works with wmv files.

Comment: I was using the the OBJECT and EMBED tags. I just looked up the events available with the VIDEO tag, and I didn't realize it supported so many. I think this will solve my problem. Thank you for your answer. I can always change the file format if necessary.

Comment: @bfavaretto you are right. I guess he can use the free Miro video converter to convert it to whatever format he needs. mp4, webm etc.

Comment: HTML5 has the *abilitiy* to support `.wmv`s, its just that only one or two browsers supports it (like Chrome).

Comment: So - back to square one. If I include an HTML5 tag, I alienate anyone using XP (which lots of businesses are still using). IE 9 cannot be installed on XP, and IE 8 doesn't support the VIDEO tag. I think I might have to go the Flash route. It is well supported and Adobe offers tools to control and monitor playback.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a similar application to this in the past using Flash video.  I know you said you're using .wmv but I'll share what we did as it might give you some ideas.

Basically we created a custom video player using Adobe Flex to play the video.  The video player was set up to ping a web service whenever the playback passed a specific milestone.  In our case we took the total playback time and divided it by 10 and once the playback passed each one of those 10% chunks it called the web service (PHP) and sent along the percentage viewed and the actual time into the video.  So for example a 2 minute video would first send a call with 10% and 12 seconds, the second call would be 20% and 24 seconds, etc.  By doing this we could keep track of the user's progress and also prevent the user from just scrubbing to the end of the video and calling it done since we could tell they didn't pass the other 9 milestones because there was no service call.

Again this was using Flash video but if your video player has some way of tapping into events or an API whereby you can detect the current position of the video then you might be able to accomplish something similar.  It's not perfect but it sufficed for our needs.

Comment: Actually, my very first thought was an ActiveX control that did something similar to what you do. But I was told I can't use ActiveX. I'll look into the options I have if I convert to Flash. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: No problem - if you do go the Flash video route I suggest taking a look at OSMF (www.osmf.org) and the Strobe media player - we used those as a great springboard and had the above solution up and running in just a few days.